# How to setup dev stack to compile c gtk3+ application with visual studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, gtk3, mingw-w64, win64

i'm a newbe in gtk+ development and i'm trying to compile a simple code as first test.

I'm working with Visual Studio Community 2017: i've installed msys64, updated packages and installed mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3. Now i've a "blank" visual c++ project with only test.c source file (code below); into solution properties i've added to "C/C++ -> Other include directories" these entries (as seen in a old guide for VC++ 2008):
 C:\msys64\mingw64\include\atk-1.0; C:\msys64\mingw64\include\cairo; C:\msys64\mingw64\include\glib-2.0; C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\glib-2.0\include; C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gdk-pixbuf-2.0; C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0; C:\msys64\mingw64\include\pango-1.0;

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void on_window_closed (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data) {
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkWidget *window, *label, *box, *button ;
    gtk_init(&argc,&argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "Test GTK+3");
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    label = gtk_label_new("Hello!");
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello!");
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (box), label, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (box), button, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

As result the compiling phase produce linker error: trying to add to the project resources the files "libgobject-2.0.dll.a" and "libgtk-3.dll.a" from "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib" folder i obtain runtime errors for missing dlls.
I didn't found a valid guide for my setup.